# Reverse proxy 2 subdomains to single server in Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have trouble configuring 2 subdomains on the same server through a reverse proxy.

The situation: 3 servers with Raspbian Stretch and Apache 2.4:

- Server #1 serves `somedomain.com` and does a reverse proxy for `otherdomain.com`, `sub1.otherdomain.com` and `sub2.otherdomain.com`
- Server #2 serves `otherdomain.com`
- Server #3 serves `sub1.otherdomain.com` and `sub2.otherdomain.com`

`somedomain.com`, `otherdomain.com` and `sub1.otherdomain.com` work fine but I'm having trouble with `sub2.otherdomain.com`: it leads to `somedomain.com`.

This is how I configured the reverse proxy in `etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` on server #1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName sub1.otherdomain.com
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.111/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.111/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName sub2.otherdomain.com
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.111/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.111/
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is how I configured `etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` on server #3:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub1.otherdomain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/username/website1/public_html
        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For

        <Directory /home/username/website1/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub2.otherdomain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/username/website2/public_html
        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For

        <Directory /home/username/website2/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: it's Google Chrome's cache. It somehow cached the redirect from when I was still playing around with the Apache configuration files.

It didn't work in Google Chrome's 'normal mode' but it worked fine in incognito mode and other browsers/devices.

I found a question about [clearing this cache](https://superuser.com/q/304589/616867) on superuser.com and [this answer was helpful](https://superuser.com/a/869739/616867) for clearing the the redirect from cache in Google Chrome without clearing the entire cache.

At the time of writing:

1. Open the *Developer Tools* panel (<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on Mac, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on Windows)
2. Click and hold the reload icon [image]
3. A menu will open

   [image]
4. Choose the 3rd option from this menu ("Empty Cache and Hard Reload")